# Xcode watchkit openParentApplication objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, watchkit

Hey I have made an application for my phone that can unlock/lock etc my car. Basically the iphone interface is just 4 buttons: lock, unlock, trunk, and connect. When ever I press a button a writes something to my arduino located inside of my car. I was wondering if I could "copy" these four buttons onto my apple watch. What I mean by that is that can I use openParentApplication to do that or is there some other command I could use to simulate so say button presses on my iphone when the button is clicked on my apple watch.

Code for Iphone buttons:

```
- (IBAction)lockCar:(UIButton *)sender;{
    NSString *string = @"l";
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (bleShield.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        [bleShield write:data];
    }
}

- (IBAction)trunkCar:(UIButton *)sender;{
    NSString *string = @"t";
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (bleShield.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        [bleShield write:data];
    }

}

- (IBAction)unlockCar:(UIButton *)sender;{
    NSString *string = @"u";
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (bleShield.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        [bleShield write:data];
    }
}
```

Code for Apple Watch so far:

```
- (IBAction)carConnect {
}

- (IBAction)carUnlock {
}

- (IBAction)carLock {
}

- (IBAction)carTrunk {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCSession to establish communication between the WatchKit extension and the companion app.
Communication channel is established as:

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    WCSession* session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];
}
```

The WCSessionDelegate must also be implemented to respond messages.

The session must be activated on each side.
Then you can send messages with `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` and receive with `session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:` to execute those tasks.

I recommend reading the [WatchKit Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/) and [this article on Watchkit communication patterns](http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is it possible if you can tell me how to implement this into my code?

Comment: @Nipunp8 I am sure you can do it after reading the second article I linked. First, establish the WCSession both in the companion app (iPhone app) and in the WatchKit extension. Second, use sendmessage in the WatchKit extension, and handle it in the companion app with didreceivemessage. You send a dictionary from the WatchKit extension through with the car command and call your car function in the companion app.